# Intellij, Git and branches

Tags: git, intellij-idea, version-control

I'm in a project with 2 other developers.
A short while back one of the other devs tried to create a new testing branch. He figured that he didn't know Git well enough to keep merging stuff and moved back to using the trunk. Since then Git went all wonky.

We now have 3 branches(?), or a trunk and 2 branches.
`HEAD`, `master` and `origin/master`.

Which of these branches is the trunk (assuming `HEAD`), and how can we prevent our commits from entering the wrong branch?
Note that the approach to pushing hasn't changed. All we do is locally commit our changes, then push them to our Git server. We do that every single time, and still it manages to sometimes push to the wrong branch. This is all done from Intellij, no command line Git is used.

How to prevent this behaviour from happening? We just want to use the trunk to host our code. We're done with Git going wonky :p

Below screenshot should explain the current situation.
We have 3 developers, `Bas` `p` and `w`. I have removed the useless commit messages from this screenshot

Notice that at one point (in the early commits) we all committed to `HEAD`, while shortly after that `p` suddenly committed to `origin/master` and it wasn't on the same life line as `HEAD` anymore. This caused conflicts and the need to merge those branches.

[image: git lifelines in Intellij]

In short;
Which branch is the actual trunk and how to make sure that no commits accidently enter a wrong branch? Is this an issue of Intellij, Git or our own configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Which branch is the actual trunk...

"Trunk" isn't a concept in Git as much as it is in Subversion, but since you're referring to the single source of truth on your project, that *should* be the master branch.

A Git person would expect the master branch to contain the main core of the code in a working state.

> ...and how to make sure that no commits accidentally enter a wrong branch?

You shouldn't be encountering any strange behavior, as IntelliJ's Git tool should be pushing to the same branch that you're on; look down in the bottom right corner to verify which branch it's on.

[image]

Depending on the Git version you're using, you may be pushing all of the branches, so you could adjust [the global config property](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config) `push.default` to `simple`.

Alternatively, be sure that you're getting the latest code from that branch; use VCS >  Git > Pull to ensure that you're pulling updates.

Comment: It actually is what we wanted. We go through the process of testing our code and only push it when we're certain it's production ready. The main issue is that some of our commits are being pushed to master, while other's are being pushed to origin/master. This has led to several conflicts because of the wrong branch being pulled on one of the other dev's projects

Comment: You can't push a commit to `master`, that's just...a local commit.  `master` is your local branch and `origin/master` is your remote branch (which you would push to).  Don't conflate the terminology of pushing and committing, as you'll only confuse yourself.  No hard feelings; it's a common misconception.

Comment: Just remember, you've *committed* to `master`, but you need to still *push* to `origin/master`.

Comment: Thanks, sorry for confusing you with a bad terminology. I am aware that I push to origin/master. As a matter of fact, we all push to origin/master. Yet sometimes it still ends up in a different branch, disabling us from checking out our partners code. Notice the screenshot, where at some point there are 4 life lines next to each other, and at another point it suddenly pushed to origin/master, and it wasn't the same as `HEAD` anymore. This is our main issue

Comment: So are you sure you're pushing to the branch you say you are?  Consider using the command line tools more and get more insight into where your code is going.

Comment: Well I think that's the problem. It looks like Intellij sometimes feels like `origin/master` is more suitable than our `HEAD`. None of us have enough experience with the command line to actually be able to work with it. But shouldn't Intellij cover that for us?

Comment: It appeared that Intellij/Git were showing the right behaviour, but our limited knowledge on either subjects prevented us from seeing the actual source of our problems. Your explanation was right and therefor your answer is accepted. Thanks for the help

Answer (score -1):

In this case, `HEAD`, `master`, and `origin/master` are all (roughly) names for the same thing.  You only have one local branch: `master`; and one "upstream" branch: `origin/master`.  What you see is *exactly* as expected.  You are all up-to-date, so `master` and `origin/master` point to the same thing.  And that's what you have checked out, so `HEAD` points there as well.

This is not always the case, but just after a push or a fast-forward pull it usually is.

Comment: But they are only up to date after we went through the process of merging several conflicted branches. While all we wanted was 1 main branch where all of our commits reside

Comment: Only in this case would I consider `HEAD == master == origin/master`.  In other cases, that is very much *not* the case.